# Set /etc/hostname in running container using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container

My docker-compose.yml is as follow:

```
version:                  "3"
services:

  write:
    image:                apachegeode/geode:1.11.0
    container_name:       write
    hostname:             a.b.net
    expose:
      - "8080"
      - "10334"
      - "40404"
      - "1099"
      - "7070"
    ports:
     - "10220:10334"
    volumes:
     - ./scripts/:/scripts/
    command:              /scripts/sleep.sh gfsh start locator ...
    networks:
      my-network:
    deploy:
      replicas:           1
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus:           '0.50'
          memory:         512M
        reservations:
          cpus:           '0.50'
          memory:         512M
      restart_policy:
        condition:        on-failure
    depends_on:
      - read

  read:
    image:                apachegeode/geode:1.11.0
    container_name:       read
    hostname:             a.b.net
    expose:
      - "8080"
      - "10334"
      - "40404"
      - "1099"
      - "7070"
    ports:
      - "10221:10334"
    volumes:
     - ./scripts/:/scripts/
    command:              /scripts/sleep.sh gfsh start locator ...
    networks:
      my-network:
    deploy:
      replicas:           1
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus:           '0.50'
          memory:         512M
        reservations:
          cpus:           '0.50'
          memory:         512M
      restart_policy:
        condition:        on-failure

networks:
  my-network:
```

container_name has to be "write" and "read" since they are unique containers but running on the host machine. 
 
 Setting **hostname: a.b.net** in the docker-compose.yml sets 
 
 192.168.160.2          a.b.net     a 
 
 in /etc/hosts file but 
 
 /etc/hostname show a which is only the alias name . 
 How can I set /etc/hostname with a.b.net using docker-compose.yml ? 
 
 I use

```sh
docker-compose -f my-docker-compose.yml up -d
```

to run the containers.

Comment: `a` is the hostname. Pretty sure that's the expected behavior. `a.b.net` is the "fully qualified domain name" or fqdn.

Comment: Have you already tried wrapping it in quotes? (Either single or double): `hostname:             'a.b.net'`